# Vectorized function usage and joining individual terms into a single tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, purrr, tibble

the title is vague but let me explain:
I have a non-vectorized function that outputs a 15-row table of volume estimates for a tree. Each row is a different measurement unit or portion of the input tree. I have a `Tables` argument to help the user decide what units and measurement protocol they're looking to find, but in 99% of use case scenarios, the output for a single tree's volume estimate is a tibble with more than one row.

I've removed ~20 other arguments from the function for demonstration's sake. DBH is a tree's diameter at breast height. `Vol` column is arbitrary.

```
Est1 <- TreeVol(Tables = "All", DBH = 7)
Est1
# A tibble: 15 x 3
   Tables                                DBH   Vol
   <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1. Total_Above_Ground_Cubic_Volume      7     2
 2 2. Gross_Inter_1/4inch_Vol              7     4
 3 3. Net_Scribner_Vol                     7     6
 4 4. Gross_Merchantable_Vol               7     8
 5 5. Net_Merchantable_Vol                 7    10
 6 6. Merchantable_Vol                     7    12
 7 7. Gross_SecondaryProduct_Vol           7    14
 8 8. Net_SecondaryProduct_Vol             7    16
 9 9. SecondaryProduct                     7    18
10 10. Gross_Inter_1/4inch_Vol             7    20
11 11. Net_Inter_1/4inch_Vol               7    22
12 12. Gross_Scribner_SecondaryProduct     7    24
13 13. Net_Scribner_SecondaryProduct       7    26
14 14. Stump_Volume                        7    28
15 15. Tip_Volume                          7    30
```

the user can utilize the `Tables` argument as so:

```
Est2 <- TreeVol(Tables = "Scribner_BF", DBH = 7)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Tables                                DBH   Vol
  <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl>
1 3. Net_Scribner_Vol                     7     6
2 12. Gross_Scribner_SecondaryProduct     7    24
3 13. Net_Scribner_SecondaryProduct       7    26
```

The problem arises in that I'd like to write a vectorized version of this function that can calculate the volume for an entire .csv of tree inventory data. Ideally, I'd like the multi-row outputs that relate to a single tree to output as one long tibble, with each 15-row default output filtered by what the user passes to the `Tables` argument as so:

```
Est3 <- VectorizedTreeVol(Tables = "Scribner_BF", DBH = c(7, 21, 26))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Tables                                DBH   Vol
  <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl>
1 3. Net_Scribner_Vol                     7     6
2 12. Gross_Scribner_SecondaryProduct     7    24
3 13. Net_Scribner_SecondaryProduct       7    26
4 3. Net_Scribner_Vol                     21   18
5 12. Gross_Scribner_SecondaryProduct     21   72
6 13. Net_Scribner_SecondaryProduct       21   76
7 3. Net_Scribner_Vol                     26    8
8 12. Gross_Scribner_SecondaryProduct     26   78
9 13. Net_Scribner_SecondaryProduct       26   84
```

To achieve this, I wrote a `for()` loop that acts as the heart of the vectorized function. I've heard from multiple people that it's very inefficient (and I agree), but it works with the principle I'd like to achieve, in theory. Nothing I've found on this topic has suggested a better idea for application in a vectorized function like mine.
The general setup for the loop looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(DBH)){
Output <- VectorizedTreeVol(Tables = Tables[[i]], DBH = DBH[[i]]) %>% 
  purrr::reduce(dplyr::full_join, by = NULL) %>% 
  SuppressWarnings()
```

and in functions where the non-vectorized output is always a single row, the heart of its respective vectorized function doesn't need to be encased in a `for()` loop and looks like this:

```
Output <- OtherVectorizedFunction(Tables = Tables, DBH = DBH) %>% 
  purrr::reduce(dplyr::full_join, by = ColumnNames) %>% #ColumnNames is a vector with all of the output's column names
  SuppressWarnings()
```

This specific call to `reduce()` has worked pretty well when I've used it to vectorize the other functions in the project, but I'm open to suggestions regarding how to join the output tables. I've been stuck on this dilemma for a few months now, and any help regarding how to achieve what this `for()` loop is striving for in theory would be awesome. Is having a vectorized function that outputs a tibble like `Est3` even possible? Any feedback/comments are much appreciated.

Comment: There is a little tweak to your original function. Inside the function, where you have `DBH == ...` used for subsetting, instead you need to use `DBH %in% ...` I do not know what your code has (ie `DBH == x`) or even `DBH == k` i dont know the variable name used. Thats why I used `...`

Comment: If you're just stacking the results (I think you are??) then `purrr::reduce(dplyr::full_join, by = NULL)` is much more complicated than necessary, `dplyr::bind_rows()` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Given this function:

```
TreeVol <- function(DBH) {
  data.frame(Tables = c("Tree_Vol", "Intercapillary_transfusion", "Woodiness"),
             Vol = c(DBH^2, sqrt(DBH) + 3, sin(DBH)),
             DBH)
}
```

We could put our `DBH` parameters into `purrr::map` and then `bind_rows` to get a data.frame.

```
VecTreeVol <- function(DBH) {
  DBH %>%
  purrr::map(TreeVol) %>%
  bind_rows()
}
```

Result

```
> VecTreeVol(DBH = 1:3)

                      Tables       Vol DBH
1                   Tree_Vol 1.0000000   1
2 Intercapillary_transfusion 4.0000000   1
3                  Woodiness 0.8414710   1
4                   Tree_Vol 4.0000000   2
5 Intercapillary_transfusion 4.4142136   2
6                  Woodiness 0.9092974   2
7                   Tree_Vol 9.0000000   3
8 Intercapillary_transfusion 4.7320508   3
9                  Woodiness 0.1411200   3
```